# Problem with Simba ODBC driver for Big Query : General error: Year is out of valid range: 1400..9999

Tags: excel, google-bigquery, odbc

I have datas hosted on Big Query. I try to access to this data from Excel thanks to Simba ODBC driver.
On my computer, it works fine and I can query différents table.

A colleague try to access to the same tables, but he gets the following error :

```
DataSource.Error : ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Simba][ODBC] (10001) General error: Year is out of valid range: 1400..9999
Détails :
    DataSourceKind=Odbc
    DataSourcePath=dsn=Big Query for Excel
    OdbcErrors=[Table]
```

I check Excel version, ODBC simba version, and Excel regional configuration, and there are the same.
I think error is cause by date field with the value "0001-01-01", but i do not understand why it works on my computer and not on colleagues's computer.

If you have any idea of the cause of the problem, it will be very helpfull to share it

Comment: Ensure that the date formats on your colleague's computer match the date formats on your computer. Make sure that your colleague is using the same version of the Simba ODBC driver as you are. Confirm that both computers have the same Excel add-ins installed. Sometimes, third-party add-ins can interfere with data retrieval and cause issues.

Comment: Hi SANN3

Thank you for your answser.

I checked all these points with my colleagues and there is no differences . After additional tests, it seems that it is due to the volume of data. 

I am surprised because for me, in preview mode, Power Query does not download all the data.

I think this is it, because if start with a blank query, and add filters to limit the number of rows returned, I don't have the problem.